# Get User Username - discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

hello guys I don't know how to get user username in discord I was trying but I cant.
something about `message.author.username`
Any suggest for that?

Comment: What have you tried? What was wrong with it? Any error messages? Also, try to read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) first.

Comment: Have a look at the documentation for discord.js, specifically for Message and User https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get a username you could use 2 common methods:

```js
let userName = message.author.username;
```

Or alternatively:

```js
//you can search for a username
let userName = client.users.cache.find(user => user.username === "username here").username;
//note: this depends on if the user is cached or not (link below)
```

[Discord.js Guide](https://discordjs.guide/) - [Common Mistakes and Syntax Errors](https://discordjs.guide/additional-info/changes-in-v12.html)